# Why does $A = X-B$ is equivalent to $A \cup B = X$ and $A \cap B = \emptyset$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, relations

I was looking at a solution to the problem and it says that $A = X-B$ is equivalent to $A \cup B = X$ and $A \cap B = \emptyset$. I am wondering why this is true?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: These conditions are only equivalent if $B \subseteq X$. But anyway, intuitively: $A=X-B$ means $A$ is the set of all things in $X$ that aren't in $B$. The other condition means everything in $X$ is in one of $A$ or $B$, but not both. Can you see why these conditions are equivalent?

Answer (score 2):

It's not true unless we also know that $B \subseteq X$. Otherwise, for a counterexample, consider $A = \{1, 2\}$ and $B = \{3, 4\}$ and $X = \{1, 2, 3\}$. Then:
$$
A = \{1, 2\} = X - B
$$
yet on the other hand:
$$
A \cup B = \{1,2,3,4\} \neq \{1,2,3\} = X
$$

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{align}A \cup B & = (X-B)\cup B 
\\[1ex] & = \{x: (x\in X \wedge x\notin B)\vee x\in B\} 
\\[1ex] & =\{x: x\in X \vee x\in B\} 
\\[1ex] & = X \cup B
\\[3ex] A \cap B & = (X-B)\cap B 
\\[1ex] & = \{x: (x\in X \wedge x\notin B)\wedge x\in B\} 
\\[1ex] & =\{x: x\in B\wedge x\notin B\} 
\\[1ex] & = \varnothing\end{align}$

Comment: Your third equality is false.

Comment: Yes... yes it was.